# Error with SemidefiniteOptimization

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

I have the following semidefinite problem $$\min_{\textbf{Y}\geq 0} Tr[\textbf{F}_0\textbf{Y}]$$ with constraint given by $$Tr[\textbf{F}_j\textbf{Y}] = c_j$$ and in which $\textbf{Y} $ is Hermitian. In my case the matrix are $8\times 8 $ and some of them are defined as

```
Set1Constraint1[rx_, ry_, rz_] = 
  ArrayFlatten[{{0, 
     Transpose[
      ArrayFlatten[{{\[Rho][rx, ry, rz], 0, 0, 0, 
         0}}]]}, {ArrayFlatten[{{\[Rho][rx, ry, rz], 0, 0, 0, 0}}], 
     0}}];
Set1Constraint2[rx_, ry_, rz_] = 
  ArrayFlatten[{{0, 
     Transpose[
      ArrayFlatten[{{0, 0, \[Rho][rx, ry, rz], 0, 
         0}}]]}, {ArrayFlatten[{{0, 0, \[Rho][rx, ry, rz], 0, 0}}], 
     0}}];
Set1Constraint3[rx_, ry_, rz_] = 
  ArrayFlatten[{{0, 
     Transpose[
      ArrayFlatten[{{0, 0, 
         0, \[Rho][rx, ry, rz]}}]]}, {ArrayFlatten[{{0, 0, 0, 
        0, \[Rho][rx, ry, rz]}}], 0}}];
```

and so on (I do not write all of them for the sake of simplicity).There are $40$ constraints anyway.To evaluate the semidefinite problem I Write

```
    Evaluation[rx_, ry_, rz_] := 
     SemidefiniteOptimization[
      Tr[Set0Constraint[rx, ry, 
         rz].Y], {Tr[Set1Constraint1[rx, ry, rz].Y] - 2*rx == 0, 
       Tr[Set1Constraint2[rx, ry, rz].Y] - 2*ry == 0, 
       Tr[Set1Constraint3[rx, ry, rz].Y] - 2*rz == 0, 
       Tr[Set2Constraint11[rx, ry, rz].Y] - 2 == 0, 
       Tr[Set2Constraint22[rx, ry, rz].Y] - 2 == 0, 
       Tr[Set2Constraint33[rx, ry, rz].Y] - 2 == 0, 
       Tr[Set2Constraint12[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set2Constraint13[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set2Constraint21[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set2Constraint23[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set2Constraint31[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set2Constraint32[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set3Constraint11[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set3Constraint12[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set3Constraint13[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set3Constraint14[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set3Constraint21[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set3Constraint22[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set3Constraint23[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set3Constraint24[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set3Constraint31[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set3Constraint32[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set3Constraint33[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set3Constraint34[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set4Constraint11[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set4Constraint12[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set4Constraint13[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set4Constraint14[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set4Constraint21[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set4Constraint22[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set4Constraint23[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set4Constraint24[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set4Constraint31[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set4Constraint32[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set4Constraint33[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set4Constraint34[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set5Constraint1[rx, ry, rz].Y] - Sqrt[2] == 0, 
       Tr[Set5Constraint2[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set5Constraint3[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set5Constraint4[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0, 
       Tr[Set5Constraint5[rx, ry, rz].Y] == 0}, Flatten[Y]]
```

where I defined $\textbf {Y} $ as

```
    Y = Table["y" <> ToString[i] <> ToString[j], {i, 1, n*d + d}, {j, 1, n*d + d}];
```

to define the matrix on which we minimise. I have a problem and a question

1. The problem is that when I try to run Evaluation[0.1, 0.1, 0.1] I obtain the following error

```
    SemidefiniteOptimization : "The objective \
SemidefiniteOptimization[<<1>>] is not a vector of     numeric values"
```

2. The second, the question is how can I write the condition $\textbf{Y} > 0 $ and the condition of Hermiticity of $\textbf {Y} $?

Comment: I think you forgot to include '_the following error_'. Also that's a lot of constraint functions and don't have definitions for all of them - if you cannot paste them all here, wouldn't it be easier to write one function which can generate the constraints? The first three look nearly identical and could be simplified using `RotateRight` or by specifying parameters to the functions indicating the position of `ρ[rx, ry, rz]` in the final matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much, I added the error I encounter. The other constraints have all the same shape and it is quite difficult to write a function that generate them all due their nature.

Comment: The way you define Y is bad - I would recommend doing `Y = Array[y, {n*d + d, n*d + d}];` instead. Does your objective `Tr[Set0Constraint[rx, ry, rz].Y]` evaluate to a numeric vector when you plug in values for Y and rx,ry,rz? It's possible you have symbolic things in there at the point of evaluation, or you have to pattern test with `?NumericQ`. Also we don't have a definition of `ρ` so we cannot help with that.

Comment: For Q2), add the constraint `(And @@ Thread[Flatten[Y] > 0])` and for the Hermitian constraint, that might be `(And @@ Flatten[MapThread[Equal, {Y, ConjugateTranspose[Y]}, 2]])` but I'm not sure you need this

Comment: @flinty I substituted `Y`  with your definition. The expression `Tr[Set0Constraint[rx,ry,rz].Y]` returns a scalar, real number. The definition of  $\rho$ is `\[Rho][rx_, ry_, rz_] = 1/2*(IdentityMatrix[2] + rx*PauliMatrix[1] + ry*PauliMatrix[2] +  rz*PauliMatrix[3]);`

Comment: If I add the first constraint only the error is double now: `The input for SemidefiniteOptimization is not of the correct matrix \
form and appears to have variables.  If you intend to specify the \
problem with variables, be sure to use SemidefiniteOptimization[f, \
constraints, vars]` and  `"The objective SemidefiniteOptimization[{0.6,0.05 +0.1\ \
I,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.05 -0.1\ I,<<33>>,0.,0.,0.05 -0.1\ \
I,0.4,0.,0.,0.,0.,<<14>>},<<1>>] is not a vector of numeric values"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123490/discussion-between-raskolnikov-and-flinty).